# Permute list of strings

Tags: string-manipulation, permutation

Say I have a list of strings like

```
slist={"apple","123","Car"}
```

What I want is a list of all permutations of `slist`. The result should be something like that

```
{"apple","123","Car","apple123","appleCar","apple123Car","Carapple123",...}
```

The reason for this is that I want to create a dictionary for password recovery.

Comment: Please try `Permutations[slist]`

Comment: or `Permutations[slist, All]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
StringJoin /@ Rest @ Permutations[slist, Length @ slist]
```

> {"apple", "123", "Car", "apple123", "appleCar", "123apple", "123Car", "Carapple", "Car123", "apple123Car", "appleCar123", "123appleCar", "123Carapple", "Carapple123", "Car123apple"}